# no matching function for call to ‘Tree<int>::operator==(Tree<int>*&, Tree<int>*&) const’

Tags: c++, tree

I've this generic tree implementation and i'm getting this error writing a recursive tree comparison.
On line 89 i get this error:
no matching function for call to ‘Tree::operator==(Tree*&, Tree*&) const’
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template<class T> class Tree {
public:
    Tree();
    Tree(const T& pNode);
    virtual ~Tree();

    const T& getNode();
    void setNode(const T& pNode);

    void addChild(Tree<T>* pChild);
    const Tree<T>* getChild(int pIndex);

    const std::list<Tree<T>*>* getChildren();
    void printTree(const Tree<T>* pTree, int pLevel);

    bool operator==(const Tree<T>& other) const;
private:
    T node;
    std::list<Tree<T>*>* children;
};

template<class T> Tree<T>::Tree(const T& pNode) :
        node(pNode), children(nullptr) {
}

template<class T> Tree<T>::Tree() :
        node(T()), children(nullptr) {
}

template<class T> Tree<T>::~Tree() {
    delete children;
}

template<class T> const T& Tree<T>::getNode() {
    return this->node;
}

template<class T> void Tree<T>::setNode(const T& pNode) {
    this->node = pNode;
}

template<class T> void Tree<T>::addChild(Tree<T>* pChild) {
    if (this->children == nullptr) {
        this->children = new std::list<Tree<T>*>();
    }

    this->children->push_back(pChild);
}

template<class T> const Tree<T>* Tree<T>::getChild(int pIndex) {
    if (true) {
    }

    return this->children[pIndex];
}

template<class T> void Tree<T>::printTree(const Tree<T>* pTree,
        int pLevel = 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pLevel; i++) {
        std::cout << "  "; // Print 2 spaces for each level
    }

    std::cout << pTree->node << std::endl;

    if (pTree->children != nullptr) {
        for (typename std::list<Tree<T>*>::iterator i =
                pTree->children->begin(); i != pTree->children->end(); i++) {
            printTree(*i, pLevel + 1);
        }
    }
}

template<class T> const std::list<Tree<T>*>* Tree<T>::getChildren() {
    return this->children;
}

template<class T> bool Tree<T>::operator==(const Tree<T>& other) const {
    bool ret = false;

    if (this->node == other.node) {
        ret = true;
        typename std::list<Tree<T>*>::iterator i, j;
        for (i = this->children->begin(), j = other.children->begin();
                i != this->children->end() && j != other.children->end();
                i++, j++) {
            ret = ret && (operator==(*i, *j)); // This is the line with the error
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Tree<int> a1(1), b1(2), c1(3);
    Tree<int> a2(1), b2(2), c2(3);

    a1.addChild(&b1);
    a1.addChild(&c1);

    a2.addChild(&b2);
    a2.addChild(&c2);

    bool ret = a1 == a2;

    std::cout << ret << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mind marking the line? I can't recall the last time I manualy counted to 89 :)

Comment: @jrok i've added a comment on that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators to `Tree*`s when dereferenced return `Tree*`s.

You are calling `Tree::operator==`, or the free `operator==`, on two `Tree*`s, and such is not found (not surprisingly).  If you want to compare the trees, you need to dereference again.  And use infix `==` while you are at it.  So `**i==**j`.

You should first check for null -- `*i&&*j&&(**i==**j)` -- except maybe you want two null pointers to compare equal? `(...)||(!*j&&!*i)`  Or as a possible optimization: `(*i==*j)||(*i&&*j&&(**i==**j))` which also skips equality when the two pointers are the same, and reduces branches.

Alternatively if you do not want to compare the `Tree` but rather the pointers, do `*i == *j`.